# Changing values of parameters after binding when calling query at Oracle database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, tomcat, mybatis

We have in company the application that was developed using Java 7, Spring Framework 3.1.2, MyBatis 3.1.1, MyBatis Spring 1.2.2, JasperReports 6.1.0, etc. Application works at Tomcat 7.0.35, uses Tomcat Connection Pool for connection to Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit. JRE version 1.7.0_09-b05. Application works at RHEL Server 6.5.

From time to time problem arises, which then disappears after a few hours (3-6 hours), and sometimes a couple of days (1-3 days). When Web Service that creates a report, the application calls method from MyBatis mapper which returns List<MonthlyReport>, then application passes this list to JasperReport engine which create report on file system, and at the end application returns stream of file at response (MTOM). The problem is that periodically when trying to run a query in the database to create a report, causes the following exception:

```
ERROR 2015-07-23 11:44:03,012 [http-bio-8280-exec-2] exception type: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException
ERROR 2015-07-23 11:44:03,012 [http-bio-8280-exec-2] exception message: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P010
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

This is the query:

```
<select id="getMonthlyReportData" resultType="MonthlyReport" parameterType="map">
<![CDATA[
SELECT r.bank_name bankName,
       r.user_name userName,
       r.descr userDescription,
       CASE WHEN r.parent_bank_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END isParentBankInt,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN r.p_type NOT IN ('SS', 'DR') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) postpaidPaymentCount,
       SUM (CASE WHEN r.p_type NOT IN ('SS', 'DR') THEN r.amount ELSE 0 END) postpaidPaymentAmount,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN r.p_type = 'SS' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) prepaidPaymentCount,
       SUM (CASE WHEN r.p_type = 'SS' THEN r.amount ELSE 0 END) prepaidPaymentAmount,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN r.p_type = 'DR' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) depositRepayCount,
       SUM (CASE WHEN r.p_type = 'DR' THEN r.amount ELSE 0 END) depositRepayAmount
  FROM (SELECT q.queue_id,
               q.amount,
               q.p_type,
               q.user_name,
               q.action_date,
               b.parent_bank_id,
               U.descr,
               b.bank_name
          FROM rbp_queue q, rbp_all_banks b, rbp_users U
         WHERE     q.user_name = U.user_name
               AND U.working_bank_id = b.bank_id
               AND q.err_code = -1000000
               AND q.action_date BETWEEN TO_DATE (#{start_date, javaType=STRING, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
                                     AND TO_DATE (#{end_date,   javaType=STRING, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
               AND U.working_bank_id IN
                    (SELECT bank_id
                       FROM rbp_all_banks
                      WHERE bank_id = #{bank_id, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC} OR parent_bank_id = #{bank_id, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC})
        UNION
        SELECT qa.queue_id,
               qa.amount,
               qa.p_type,
               qa.user_name,
               qa.action_date,
               ba.parent_bank_id,
               Ua.descr,
               ba.bank_name
          FROM sysadm.rbp_queue_arch@azis_archdb qa,
               rbp_all_banks ba,
               rbp_users Ua
         WHERE     qa.user_name = Ua.user_name
               AND Ua.working_bank_id = ba.bank_id
               AND qa.err_code = -1000000
               AND qa.action_date BETWEEN TO_DATE (#{start_date, javaType=STRING, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
                                      AND TO_DATE (#{end_date,   javaType=STRING, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
               AND Ua.working_bank_id IN
                    (SELECT bank_id
                       FROM rbp_all_banks
                      WHERE bank_id = #{bank_id, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC} OR parent_bank_id = #{bank_id, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC})) r
         GROUP BY r.bank_name,
                  r.user_name,
                  r.descr,
                  CASE WHEN r.parent_bank_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         ORDER BY isParentBankInt DESC, bankName, userName
]]>
```

Application don't use date type parameter, because the Oracle in this case uses a different plan, and the query runs for a long time. For this reason, application passes to the query date as text and then converts it to date using the TO_DATE function.
Log records from MyBatis:

```
DEBUG 2015-07-22 15:10:52,720 [http-apr-8281-exec-2] ooo Using Connection [ProxyConnection[PooledConnection[oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@344482ac]]]
DEBUG 2015-07-22 15:10:52,724 [http-apr-8281-exec-2] ==>  Preparing: SELECT r.bank_name bankName, r.user_name userName, r.descr userDescription, ...
DEBUG 2015-07-22 15:10:52,725 [http-apr-8281-exec-2] ==> Parameters: 20150601000000(String), 20150621235959(String), 31(Integer), 31(Integer), 20150601000000(String), 20150621235959(String), 31(Integer), 31(Integer)
```

As seen here, MyBatis passes date parameters (as string) to query, but if to see Oracle trace we can see that, value of date parameters are "" (not null, but two double quotes).

Calling of

```
SELECT TO_DATE ('', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') FROM dual
```

at TOAD returns null value, but

```
SELECT TO_DATE ('""', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') FROM dual
```

raises exception: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0.

The strange thing is that when there is a problem on the server, at the same time application works without problems (creates this report) on other computers, such as my working laptop.
Below is a part of trace file of Oracle database when problem occurred:

```
     Bind#0
      oacdty=01 mxl=32(28) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000010 frm=02 csi=2000 siz=224 off=0
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf330908  bln=32  avl=28  flg=05
      value=""
     Bind#1
      oacdty=01 mxl=32(28) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000010 frm=02 csi=2000 siz=0 off=32
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf330928  bln=32  avl=28  flg=01
      value=""
     Bind#2
      oacdty=02 mxl=22(22) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000000 frm=02 csi=2000 siz=0 off=64
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf330948  bln=22  avl=02  flg=01
      value=31
     Bind#3
      oacdty=02 mxl=22(22) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000000 frm=02 csi=2000 siz=0 off=88
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf330960  bln=22  avl=02  flg=01
      value=31
     Bind#4
      oacdty=01 mxl=32(28) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000010 frm=02 csi=2000 siz=0 off=112
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf330978  bln=32  avl=28  flg=01
      value=""
     Bind#5
      oacdty=01 mxl=32(28) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000010 frm=02 csi=2000 siz=0 off=144
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf330998  bln=32  avl=28  flg=01
      value=""
     Bind#6
      oacdty=02 mxl=22(22) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000000 frm=02 csi=2000 siz=0 off=176
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf3309b8  bln=22  avl=02  flg=01
      value=31
     Bind#7
      oacdty=02 mxl=22(22) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000000 frm=02 csi=2000 siz=0 off=200
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf3309d0  bln=22  avl=02  flg=01
      value=31
```

Below is a part of trace file of Oracle database when problem didn't occur:

```
     Bind#0
      oacdty=01 mxl=32(14) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000010 frm=01 csi=31 siz=224 off=0
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf323e50  bln=32  avl=14  flg=05
      value="20150601000000"
     Bind#1
      oacdty=01 mxl=32(14) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000010 frm=01 csi=31 siz=0 off=32
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf323e70  bln=32  avl=14  flg=01
      value="20150621235959"
     Bind#2
      oacdty=02 mxl=22(22) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000000 frm=01 csi=31 siz=0 off=64
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf323e90  bln=22  avl=02  flg=01
      value=31
     Bind#3
      oacdty=02 mxl=22(22) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000000 frm=01 csi=31 siz=0 off=88
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf323ea8  bln=22  avl=02  flg=01
      value=31
     Bind#4
      oacdty=01 mxl=32(14) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000010 frm=01 csi=31 siz=0 off=112
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf323ec0  bln=32  avl=14  flg=01
      value="20150601000000"
     Bind#5
      oacdty=01 mxl=32(14) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000010 frm=01 csi=31 siz=0 off=144
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf323ee0  bln=32  avl=14  flg=01
      value="20150621235959"
     Bind#6
      oacdty=02 mxl=22(22) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000000 frm=01 csi=31 siz=0 off=176
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf323f00  bln=22  avl=02  flg=01
      value=31
     Bind#7
      oacdty=02 mxl=22(22) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
      oacflg=03 fl2=1000000 frm=01 csi=31 siz=0 off=200
      kxsbbbfp=9fffffffbf323f18  bln=22  avl=02  flg=01
      value=31
```

Note the values of binds:0, 1, 4, 5. When problem the value is **value=""**.

The problem is not related to MyBatis, since before the request was inside the compiled JasperReports file (monthlyReport.jasper) and the application passed the database connection to JasperReports engine to create the report. JasperReports itself connected to database and ran the query. MyBatis was not used for creation of report, but used in the application for all other purposes. The same Oracle error (ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0) periodically issued and there. From old log file:

```
    ERROR 2015-06-11 08:57:17,559 [http-apr-8280-exec-9] Fill 1: exception
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : monthlyReport_New32Dataset321_1432644594876_272524
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:240)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1087)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:668)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1281)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:900)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:651)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:203)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P002
    ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor349.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
            at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.java:235)
            at $Proxy99.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
            at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:233)
            ... 11 more
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: It looks like your query is wrong, and to be honest, this is a very specific problem, not a generic one. As we have no idea of what exactly the code does, it is more harder to isolate the issue. Good luck. Also, the error is clear :     ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 . Try to start here.

Comment: Oracle expects strings in single quotes, so an empty string would be '', not '""'.  So whatever is causing the input to be double quotes is the issue.  You could solve it in the query I suppose, something like: to_date(replace('""', '"',''), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')

Comment: @Tural +1 for very precise documentation of the case (even with tkprof!).

Answer (score 0):

You are observing a **symptom**. And it is not the problem with quotes. In the trace a string parameter is shown with doulbe quotes. i.e.

```
value="20150621235959"
```

means the client passed a string '20150621235959' and

```
value=""
```

means the client passed an empty string ''. Which leads the the ORA-12801

The **root cause** is that the client is able to pass an empty string to the database.

The predicates

```
action_date BETWEEN date1 and date2
```

returns no row if one or both of the dates is NULL. If you don't trust simple run this query

```
 -- return nothing
 SELECT * FROM dual where sysdate between to_date('','ddmmyyyy') and to_date('','ddmmyyyy');
```

There is no point why the client should send empty strings to the database, if you know, that nothing will be returned.

So IMHO there should be some validation in the client enforcing only valid strings (at least the proper lenght) are accepted. This will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be bad data getting the the query.  You'll need to identify the cause of empty strings to truly resolve this issue, but you can fix the query so it doesn't fail by replacing the start and end date binds like this:

Change this:

```
#{start_date, javaType=STRING, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
```

to this:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(#{start_date, javaType=STRING, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, '[0-9]{14}')
```

Doing the same for your end_date binds.

The `REGEXP_SUBSTR` will either return a 14 character date string or `NULL` after which the `TO_DATE` function will either yield a date value or `NULL`

`NULL`s will most likely cause your query to not return any data.